# Wait for Ajax call in function to end, THEN return object to an outside variable

Tags: javascript, json, ajax, asynchronous, endpoints

I want to use JavaScript asynchronous, as it was intended. I want to assign the recieved data/objects to as many variables as I'll need (DataModel01, DataModel02, DataModel03 and so on). The idea is that my need for API data change all the time, and I want to only have to define once where to get the data (API endpoint), and in what local variable/object to store it.

The way I'm doing it, it returns the object with recieved data from the fetchDataJSON() function. However, how do I make the return wait for the Ajax to finish? I've tried several things, including timers and callbacks, and nothing works at all.

I saw the other questions regarding ajax and async, and generally it was suggested to use callbacks. So I believe I might be offtrack, but I need a hand to figure out a way to deal with this gracefully. Do I really need to mess with timers and ugly solutions like that?

```
function fetchDataJSON(endpointUrl) {
    var returnObj = [];

    // Ajax call
    $.ajax({
      type: "GET",
      url: endpointUrl,
      dataType: 'json',
      async: true,
      success: updateData,
      error: handleError
    });

    function updateData(data) {
        returnObj = data;
    }

    function handleError(XHR, message, error) {
        console.log("Failed XHR");
    }

    return returnObj; // Return JSON object
}

var DataModel01 = fetchDataJSON( "http://mydata.com/endpoint/sweetjson" );
var DataModel02 = fetchDataJSON( "http://mydata.com/endpoint/somethingelse" );
```

---

EDIT:
I found a working solution now, yihar. I've marked the answer by Karman as accepted, as it was the one closest to the solution. My final solution, which was also inspired by a coworker, is as follows:

```
var DataModel01 = [];
var DataModel02 = [];

function fetchDataJSON(endpointUrl, callbackWhenDone) {
    // Ajax call
    $.ajax({
      type: "GET",
      url: endpointUrl,
      dataType: 'json',
      async: true,
      success: updateData,
      error: handleError
    });

    function updateData(data) {
        callbackWhenDone(data);
    }

    function handleError(XHR, message, error) {
        console.log("Failed XHR");
    }
}

fetchDataJSON(
    "http://mydata.com/endpoint/sweetjson",
    function(newData) { DataModel01 = newData; }
);

fetchDataJSON(
    "http://mydata.com/endpoint/somethingelse",
    function(newData) { DataModel02 = newData; }
);
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I return the response from an asynchronous call?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14220321/how-do-i-return-the-response-from-an-asynchronous-call)

Comment: The success function is only called if the request succeeds, it will pass the returned data as an argument to the defined callback function. I think what you have should work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
function fetchDataJSON(endpointUrl, callback) {
function updateData(data) {
    returnObj = data;

  callback(returnObj)
}

fetchDataJSON( "http://mydata.com/endpoint/sweetjson", getJson );

enter code here

function getJson(returnObj)
 {
    //do work with returnObj
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

declare var DataModel1 in first line of the code.

in success method (updateData) assign the data to DataModel1 directly. in success method itself you can differentiate with url for datamodel2